# VS2008 Debugger not displaying map data

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008

I have a class that contains various datatypes using maps.  The class functions correctly, in debug and release mode.  However, when I attempt to debug my program, the debugger can not determine what is in the multiple maps inside of the class.  Normally, I would suspect memory corruption from elsewhere, but there are no memory errors while running the program and values are set and retrieved without incident.

Here is an example of the debugger error.  The number of elements in the map are reported correctly, but the values are errors.  Interestingly, when I break inside a member function for the class containing the maps, this error doesn't occur and all the values are visible.  Also, strangely, the string map shows up without a problem.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 (SP1) on Windows 7 (64bit).  The class code is actually in a DLL loaded at startup by the client program that I'm debugging, if that makes a difference.  Any ideas are appreciated.
[image]

```
class DataTable {
public:
    std::string get_string(std::string);
    float get_float(std::string);
            (etc.)

    void set_string(std::string, std::string);
    void set_float(std::string, float);
            (etc.)

protected:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m_string_map;
    std::map<std::string, float> m_float_map;
            (etc.)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I am using std::map, I am doing a workaround just for debugging purposes:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
uint32_t num_strings_in_map = (uint32_t)m_string_map.size();
uint32_t num_floats_in_map = (uint32_t)m_float_map.size();
#endif
```

I can then set a breakpoint, or output the numbers to the screen...